# Cartoon about a monkey-like green curly hair boy

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember from my childhood watching some kind of educational euro-style animation about a boy named PocoPoco (something like that, it was Spanish-dubbed) who had curly green hair that was moving all the time, his skin was all white (as in #FFFFFF) and had a monkey tail.

He looked a bit like a lion but with human features.

The cartoon style was mostly flat.

A female narrator would describe his adventures.

The timeframe would be sometime between 1998-2004 and the show look a pinch older than those times.

[image: He looked a bit like this]

Comment: What years were your childhood? Did the show look old or new at the time? Cartoon, 3D, or clay animation? Was it stand-alone or part of another show?

Comment: In addition to what was said above, please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in :)

Comment: Around 1998 to 2004

Comment: Add that in your question please.

Comment: Added, and added a sketch

Comment: This sounds familiar now.